# SQLite View with functions?

Tags: sqlite, sql-view, fts3

So let's say I have an FTS[34] table `data`, and a regular table `info`, that are bound together by a `info.ID = data.rowid`. I have a view `master` that represents this join, that I use to query overall information.
Here are the `CREATE TABLE` statements:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE data USING fts4(
    Name,
    Keywords,
    Aliases
    Description);

CREATE TABLE info (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    -- A bunch of other columns...
    );

CREATE VIEW master AS SELECT
    info.ID AS ID
    data.Name AS Name,
    data.Keywords AS Keywords,
    data.Aliases AS Aliases,
    data.Description AS Description,
    -- A bunch of other columns...
FROM info JOIN data ON info.ID = data.rowid;
```

Now what I want to do is create another view that instead of selecting the entire cell from the `data` table, selects the result of the SQLite [snippet](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_4_2) function as performed on each column of the `data` table:

```
CREATE VIEW search AS SELECT
    master.*,
    snippet(data '<b>', '</b>', '...', 0) AS sn_Name,
    snippet(data '<b>', '</b>', '...', 1) AS sn_Keywords,
    snippet(data '<b>', '</b>', '...', 2) AS sn_Aliases,
    snippet(data '<b>', '</b>', '...', 3) AS sn_Description
FROM master JOIN data ON master.ID = data.rowid;
```

However, when I execute that statement from within Python I get the following:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "'<b>'": syntax error
```

Answer (score 1):

The comma between the `data` and `'<b>'` parameter values is missing.